Crawl unsupported metrics from Facebook Insights API and Facebook Adsmanager
I've encounted a problem. I need to get metrics from Facebook API insights (I'm using version 18) to build my own report. Some of metrics are displayed in Facebook Adsmanager, but not found in API insights. Those metrics are:

Results
Delivery
Cost per results
Post comments
New messaging contacts
Cost per new messaging contacts
3-second video plays

I've read through all Facebook Insights doc and call its API by many ways but cannot get the above metrics. So are there other ways to get those metrics either by APIs or from Facebook Adsmanager?
